# How to change my class to achieve desired request for my WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service and when this service is consumed,the request looks like following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:fin="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.Web.Service">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:CheckforActiveId>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:customerData>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <fin:Password>test</fin:Password>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <fin:UserName>test</fin:UserName>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <fin:SSN>789654123</fin:SSN>
     </tem:customerData>
  </tem:CheckforActiveId>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the classes I am using here is

**Validation.cs**

```
[DataContract]
public class Validation
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerData.cs**

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomerData : Validation
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SSN { get; set; }

}
```

Here CustomerData class inherits Validation.

Now i want to change my request class to look like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:fin="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.Web.Service">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <tem:CheckforActiveId>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:Validation>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <fin:Password>test</fin:Password>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <fin:UserName>test</fin:UserName>
     </tem:Validation>
       <tem:customerData>
       <!--Optional:-->
        <fin:SSN>789654123</fin:SSN>
     </tem:customerData>
  </tem:CheckforActiveId>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to modify my class to look like this.
I am calling my method as

```
public bool CheckforActiveLOC(CustomerData customerData)
{
  // some logic
}
```

And how to remove the optional thing in the request.

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inherting Validation class,making Validation class as one Property in CustomerData class solves this requirement.

```
public class CustomerData
{        
    public Validation validation { get; set; }        
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}
```